# Meteor app crash trying to secure it

Tags: meteor

This app was working fine till I tried to "secure it":

- remove insecure
- remvoe autopublish
- add accounts-ui accounts-password
- made some changes to the code as below

  ```
  //both.js

  FooterButtons = new Mongo.Collection('footerButtons');
  Tasks1 = new Mongo.Collection('tasks1');
  Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');
  Tasks1.allow({
    insert: function (userId, doc) {
      return userId;
    }
  });


   // deny anyone that tries to update the document userId
  Posts.deny({
      update: function (userId, docs, fields, modifier) {
     // can't change owners
     return _.contains(fields, 'userId');
     }
  });

  //server.js 
  Meteor.publish('tasks', function(){
    return Tasks.find({userId: this.userId});
   });

   Meteor.publish('tasks1', function(){
     return Tasks1.find({userId: this.userId});
   });

  Meteor.publish('footerButtons', function(){
     return FooterButtons.find({userId: this.userId});
   });
  ```

Now the app is crashing with browser saying

> /Users/myName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
>                           throw(ex);
>                                 ^
>   ReferenceError: Posts is not defined
>       at both/both.js:15:1
>       at both/both.js:20:4
>       at /Users/myName/Documents/meteor/microscope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Function.*.each.*.forEach (/Users/empl1/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
>       at /Users/myName/Documents/meteor/microscope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
>   Exited with code: 8
>   Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.

Why is it crashing and how should it be fixed? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start here:

ReferenceError: Posts is not defined at both/both.js:15:1 at both/both.js

Your are missing a collection assignment for the Posts collection.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your error message, it's because you're not defining the Posts collection.  Add this line of code:

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');
```

That will remove the error, but I think you probably copied/pasted this code from an example and want to enact a deny rule on a different collection?

Answer (score 0):

I think you already have the `post` collection definition somewhere in the project, because it worked before you removed the `autopublish` package. You should find it and put all the collection definition file into `lib` folder instead of any randomly named folder for the shake of order loading. Read more about the meteor app structure in [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp)